# how to change number 01-M-14 into 02-M-14

Tags: excel

I want to make an excel sheet having "column A" of roll number for my students and want to auto update of these roll number, this roll number have specific number from 1 to 100, but common text .sample is as
1-M-14 in row A1
I want it to auto change into "2-M-14" in row A2.

Please note that M-14 is not a date, it is a special number for morning students, while E-14 is for evening students in my sheets.

Answer (score 0):

In **A1** enter:

```
=ROW() & "-M-14"
```

and copy down